# TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to pass argument from HTML code to python flask code, but when I do I get the error:

> TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
@app.route("/LoggedOn/search", methods = ["POST"])
def search(name):  # gets a user name as an argument
    books = []
    if request.method != "POST":
        return "please log on and fill on the form"
    option = request.form['field']
    search = request.form['search']
    search = search + '%'   #begins with search, per requirement
    if (option == 'author'):
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE author LIKE :srch ", {"srch":search}).fetchall()
    elif (option == 'isbn'):
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE :srch ", {"srch":search}).fetchall()
    else: # book name cose
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :srch ", {"srch":search}).fetchall()

     return render_template("search.html", books=books, name = name)
```

Also, here is the HTML part:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search', name  )  }}" method="post">
```

Nowhere else do I call the function `search`. Why is it complaining about name not being passed then?

The HTML has it from python code like this:

```
@app.route("/LoggedOn",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def LoggedOn(name):
    return render_template("LoggedOn.html", name=name)

@app.route("/registeration", methods=["GET","POST"])
def registeration():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("uname")
        password = request.form.get("psw")
        users = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=:name", {"name":name}).fetchall()
        if users != []:
            return render_template("error-register.html")
        user = MyUser(name,password)
        user.add_to_db(db)
        return LoggedOn(name)
```

So `registeration` function has name passes to `LoggedOn`, then it passes to `loggedon.html`, then it gets passed to search function by using `url_for` as above. What is missing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're defining `LoggedOn` as a separate route. If you just want to use it as a function, don't use the `app.route` decorator on top.

If you do intend it to be a route as well, you need to make sure the arguments list matches something in the url path.

Comment: it is because it is being called from search.html file:

Comment: <form action = "{{ url_for('LoggedOn', name )}}">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Search</Button>
            </form>

Comment: I removed the route line and still getting the same error

Comment: now I'm having another problem, after I tried to remove name as an argument to search function, to see what error I get, I got an error on <form action = "{{ url_for('LoggedOn', name )}}">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Search</Button>
            </form>

Comment: saying : TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

eventually I managed to fix this by adapting the name of the route of each function to the function itself, by adding  literal to the path e.g:

```
@app.route("/LoggedOn-<string:name>",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def LoggedOn(name):
    return render_template("LoggedOn.html", name=name)

@app.route("/LoggedOn/search-<string:name>", methods = ["POST"])
def search(name):
```

now no problem at all..